# How do correctly close predictions of the Mediapipe Hand Landmark model (for web) in a react application?

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, mediapipe, html5-animation

I am using the Mediapipe Hand Landmark detection model to basically create an AR jewellery application such that when I bring my hand in the camera frame it should draw the ring image onto my finger. For model loading and prediction I've referred the [mediapipe hand landmarks web guide](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/hand_landmarker/web_js) and this [medium blog post](https://medium.com/@kiyo07/integrating-mediapipe-tasks-vision-for-hand-landmark-detection-in-react-a2cfb9d543c7). First of all, here is my react component code `RingDemo.jsx`:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { FilesetResolver, HandLandmarker } from "@mediapipe/tasks-vision";
import hand_landmarker_task from "/hand_landmarker.task";
import "./App.css"
import ringSrc from "/ring6.png"

const RingDemo = () => {
    let animationFrameId
    const videoRef = useRef(null);
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const handModel = useRef(undefined)

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const ring = useRef(null)

    const startWebcam = async () => {
        try {
            const videoOptions = {
                audio: false,
                video: {
                    height: {
                        ideal: 720
                    },
                    width: {
                        ideal: 1280
                    }
                }
            }

            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(videoOptions);
            videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
            videoRef.current.style.transform = "scaleX(-1)"
            const videoSettings = stream.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings()
            canvasRef.current.width = videoSettings.width
            canvasRef.current.height = videoSettings.height
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error accessing webcam:", error);
        }
    };

    const loadModel = async () => {
        console.log("Loading Model...");
        try {
            const vision = await FilesetResolver.forVisionTasks("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/tasks-vision@latest/wasm");

            const handLandmarkerModel = await HandLandmarker.createFromOptions(
                vision, {
                baseOptions: {
                    modelAssetPath: hand_landmarker_task,
                    delegate: "GPU",
                },
                numHands: 1,
                runningMode: "video",
            });
            handModel.current = handLandmarkerModel
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error initializing hand detection:", error);
        }
    };


    const detectHands = () => {

        // Handling the last frame which gets rendered when the component is cleaned
        if (!handModel.current && animationFrameId) {
            window.cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrameId);
            animationFrameId = null
            return
        }

        if (videoRef.current && videoRef.current.readyState >= 2) {
            const detections = handModel.current.detectForVideo(videoRef.current, performance.now());
            if (detections.landmarks) {
                drawLandmarks(detections.landmarks);
            }
        }
        animationFrameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(detectHands);
    };

    const drawLandmarks = (landmarksArray) => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

        landmarksArray.forEach(landmarks => {
            ring.current.draw(ctx, canvas, landmarks)
        });
    };

    const loadRing = () => {
        try {
            console.log("Loading Ring...");
            const ringImage = new Image()
            ringImage.src = ringSrc
            ringImage.onload = () => {
                ring.current = new Ring(ringImage)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error loading resources:", error);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            loadRing()
            await loadModel()
            setLoading(false)
        })()

        return () => {
            if (videoRef.current && videoRef.current.srcObject) {
                videoRef.current.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
            }
            if (handModel.current) {
                handModel.current.close();
            }
        };
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            if (!loading) {
                if (handModel.current) {
                    await startWebcam()
                    detectHands()
                }
            }
        })()
    }, [loading])


    return (
        <div className="main">
            {loading ? <h1>Loading Please Wait</h1> : (
                <div className="video_box">
                    <video className="video_scr" ref={videoRef} autoPlay playsInline ></video>
                    <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}></canvas>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default RingDemo;
```

Now whenever I run the react application it runs fine and I am able to see the ring on my finger. However, as soon as I save the `RingDemo.jsx` file the cleanup code in the first useEffect .i.e:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            loadRing()
            await loadModel()
            setLoading(false)
        })()

        return () => {
            if (videoRef.current && videoRef.current.srcObject) {
                videoRef.current.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
            }
            if (handModel.current) {
                handModel.current.close();

            }
        };
    }, [])
```

This (return block) gets executed and due to which `handModel.current.close();` is called. When this happens I get this log on my console:

`I0229 18:53:36.093000 1927856 gl_context_webgl.cc:132] Successfully destroyed WebGL context with handle 1 vision_wasm_internal.js:9`

After this the entire application **tab freezes** and I have no choice but to close the tab by clicking multiple times or in some cases to end the browser process itself to remove the tab.

Although if I reset the `handModel` ref in the cleanup function and reload the model by resetting the `loading` state, still I get the above mentioned log but this time everything works fine and my tab does not freeze. Like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            loadRing()
            await loadModel()
            setLoading(false)
        })()

        return () => {
            if (videoRef.current && videoRef.current.srcObject) {
                videoRef.current.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
            }
            if (handModel.current) {
                handModel.current.close();
                handModel.current = undefined
                setLoading(true)
            }
        };
    }, [])
```

Is there a correct way to close the hand landmark model's predictions? Because resetting the handModel ref is quite inefficient and I need to reload the model on every save. I am quite new to react and stackoverflow in general so, pardon my mistakes and please let me know if my question is clear or do you need any more information. Thank you very much in advance, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Removing the `react-hooks` tag since it seems your question is aimed more at working with the model. But as a sort of "workaround" *while* you are iteratively developing you might try just commenting out the `useEffect` hook's cleanup function so it's not unloading your modal and slowing you down.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese for your valuable feedback. The problem with commenting the `useEffect`'s cleanup function is that, after saving the file 3-4 times my frame rate drops quite significantly (I don't know why) and thus, commenting the cleanup function didn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe you are loading multiple duplicate models?

Comment: How can I prevent that?

Comment: Sorry, I was implying that the `useEffect` hook was running again and calling `await loadModel()` and loading another modal into memory, the implication being that after you've made code changes a few times and several modals loaded into memory somewhere that this is what is degrading performance. I'm suggesting that maybe you just comment out the `useEffect` hook after the app has rendered once and the modal is loaded so more modals aren't loaded later on hot-reloads. Other than this, no I haven't any ideas since I'm completely unfamiliar of Mediapipe Hand Landmark.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good idea to implement while developing the application. Although, I still need to find a permanent solution because I will be loading two different models and thus, I need to close one model when the second one is in use and vice versa. This could only happen if I can close or shutdown the predictions of the model without my browser tab freezing.